# Use internal Microphone with AudioKit with headphones connected

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit in Swift with ios 11 and AudioKit.
I cant get my app to use the iphone mic instead of the mic built into my headphones. They are standard apple in-ear headphones. (Wired not Bluetooth)

```
let mic = AKMicrophone()

    if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
        try! AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[1])
        try! mic.setDevice(inputs[1])
    }

AudioKit.output = mic
AudioKit.start()
```

I have tried inputs [1], [2] and [3] but there is no change. In every case it uses the microphone built into the headphones. Even though the input description for input[1] is the front facing microphone.

Comment: Have you tried [0]?